# gdal.Warp is not creating a TIFF file (very big raster)

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, vrt

My raster size is more than 6 Gb. It was created from SRTM tiles, so I wasn't even able to save it as TIFF, hence I used vrt format.
Now I want to translate it to .map, so I use:

```
warpopt = gdal.WarpOptions(xRes=90,yRes=90)
dem_resampled = gdal.Warp('dem_resampled.tif'),dem_input,options=warpopt)
optt = gdal.TranslateOptions(format='PCRaster',bandList=[1],outputType=gdalconst.GDT_Float32,metadataOptions='VS_SCALAR')
gdal.Translate('dem.map',dem_resampled,options=optt)
```

I get an error ValueError: Received a NULL pointer. as file isn't generated.
If I skip resampling, I get a .map file, but with zeros.

1. Why is the TIFF not created?
2. Maybe I can skip resampling and create a .map file directly from .vrt?

UPD: I am definitely sorry. Mounted folder was unmounted and GDAL has a strange behavior, it doed not throw an error if a path is unavailable, but it writes None as object. I delete this theme.

Comment: I would first skip Python for avoiding possible errors in self written code and test with GDAL binaries.
`gdal_translate -of PCRaster input.vrt output.map". Add `--debug on` if you get errors and want to get more information. And tiff supports much larger than 4 GB file size if it is created as BigTIFF. But using vrt is usually a more clever alternative. However, I do not see vrt input in your lines of code.

Comment: you should maybe delete your post if it was a mounting issue

Comment: You can make GDAL raise exceptions rather than fail silently by using `gdal.UseExceptions()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mounted folder which was unmounted. So, such problems as Jose said, could be avoided by gdal.UseExceptions() code.